# JQuery - Select function on autocomplete not getting called?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have the following code to add autocompletion to my textBox, autocompletion shows up and everything works, but when a user selected an item the select callback does not get called?
Any solutions?

```
$(function() {

$("#txtItem").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Correct url here",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Name,
                        value: item.Name
                    }
                }))
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                alert("sdfsdf");
                //$("#txtItemId").val(ui.item.value.ItemId);
            }
        })
    }
})

}
```

Comment: Your select is a parameter to your ajax call, not to your auto-complete call.

Comment: @cjc343 Can't believe that I spent 2 hours trying to find that out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rewrite the code to be like this :

```
$(function() {

$("#txtItem").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Correct url here",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Name,
                        value: item.Name
                    }
                }))
            }            
        })
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        alert("sdfsdf");
        //$("#txtItemId").val(ui.item.value.ItemId);
    }
})

}
```

let me know if its worked

Comment: Still missing a bunch of semicolons.

Comment: @cjc343 But its still valid Javascript

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {

$("#txtItem").autocomplete({
minLength: 1,
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Correct url here",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term: request.term
        },
        success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.Name,
                    ItemId: item.ItemId//this is will put item id in memory
                }
            }))
        }            
    })
},//this is after the source property select is an auto complete property many examples screw this up and it is in side the ajax block of code
select: function (event, ui) {
    alert("sdfsdf");
    //$("#txtItemId").val(ui.item.value.ItemId);
  }
  })}
```

here is a working example http://plnkr.co/edit/RbuRDh1xRIwyO1QamvCe?p=preview